# How to test post method in fiddler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am trying to call the following POST method `[http://localhost:45361/api/test]`, in Fiddler, with [Request Header] tab, having `[User-Agent: Fiddler, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8]` and in the [Request Body],I am passing the following request `{"tag":"5667"}` . However, its outputting an error -- > **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage post([FromBody] Query query)
    {
            IQueryable<data_qy> Data = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.tag)) //--> line causing the ERROR
            {
                var ids = query.tag.Split(',');
                var dataMatchingTags = db.data_qy.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.TAG));

                if (Data == null)
                    Data = dataMatchingTags;
                else
                    Data = Data.Union(dataMatchingTags);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
            {
                var ids = query.name.Split(',');
                var dataMatchingTags = db.data_qy.Where(c => ids.Any(id => c.Name.Contains(id)));

                if (Data == null)
                    Data = dataMatchingTags;
                else
                    Data = Data.Union(dataMatchingTags);
            }

            if (Data == null) 
                Data = db.data_qy;

            if (query.endDate != null)
            {
                Data = Data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate);
            }

            if (query.startDate != null)
            {
                Data = Data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
            }

            var data = Data.ToList();

            if (!data.Any())
            {
                var message = string.Format("No data found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }
```

Edit:
Query Class:

```
public class Query
  {

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> endDate{ get; set; }
  }
```

I am little unclear, if this is the correct approach to testing post method or if I need add further code in my above controller. Please advice. Many thanks.

Comment: The model binder cannot bind the tag value to a property on your Query class. Since it cant do this it wont create an instance of your Query class and it will remain null. Since its null you can check its properties. I've checked your request and even did a mock based on your code and it works for me. Paste your code for the query class

Comment: you CAN'T check its properties*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have updated my original post above, with my query object class. Please advice, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: That looks fine to me. Can you give me your raw request data. In fiddle go to Inspector>raw

Comment: POST http://localhost:45361/api/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:45361
Content-Length: 15

{"name":"bacm"}

Comment: Thanks your request seems ok except the post url. Its going to test. Do you have a custom route setup? I would expect this to be localhost:45361/api/{apicontroller}/post by default?

Comment: Many thanks for your help and clarifying the issue.  I do not have a custom route setup, my controller's name is 'test'(i.e localhost###/api/test). I copied the controller to a new project and seems to be working now.

Comment: I would like to ask, my authentication is get, would I also need to change that post as well.  I am using basic authentication to access test controller, please advice, if possible.  I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things that you need in fiddler is the Content-Type header specification in the post request. Web API has this concept of content negotiation based on request headers and the registration of the content negotiators in the pipeline. Please, see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) for more details.

In your case:

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Here is the whole request from the fiddler composer:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:26572
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and here is the request body:

```
{"name":"hello"}
```

With this post request, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, but I am currently using the same approach to test my post method, in regards to content-type.